# Pandas to_sql() with replace argument using SQLAlchemy raises NotImplementError

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Using pandas `to_sql(if_exists="replace")` when trying to replace a table content of db2 database results in `NotImplementedError`.

```
# versions
pd.__version__='1.2.4'
sqlalchemy.__version__='1.4.22'
```

Traceback mesage:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/wsuser/ipykernel_123/3976805911.py in <module>
      1 # try pushing by replacing the existing table
----> 2 test_df.to_sql('test_table', con=db2_engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
   2777         from pandas.io import sql
   2778 
-> 2779         sql.to_sql(
   2780             self,
   2781             name,

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
    599         )
    600 
--> 601     pandas_sql.to_sql(
    602         frame,
    603         name,

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype, method)
   1404             dtype=dtype,
   1405         )
-> 1406         table.create()
   1407 
   1408         from sqlalchemy import exc

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in create(self)
    738                 raise ValueError(f"Table '{self.name}' already exists.")
    739             elif self.if_exists == "replace":
--> 740                 self.pd_sql.drop_table(self.name, self.schema)
    741                 self._execute_create()
    742             elif self.if_exists == "append":

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in drop_table(self, table_name, schema)
   1478         schema = schema or self.meta.schema
   1479         if self.has_table(table_name, schema):
-> 1480             self.meta.reflect(only=[table_name], schema=schema)
   1481             self.get_table(table_name, schema).drop()
   1482             self.meta.clear()

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in reflect(self, bind, schema, views, only, extend_existing, autoload_replace, resolve_fks, **dialect_kwargs)
   4709             for name in load:
   4710                 try:
-> 4711                     Table(name, self, **reflect_opts)
   4712                 except exc.UnreflectableTableError as uerr:
   4713                     util.warn("Skipping table %s: %s" % (name, uerr))

<string> in __new__(cls, *args, **kw)

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py in warned(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    296                         stacklevel=3,
    297                     )
--> 298             return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    299 
    300         doc = fn.__doc__ is not None and fn.__doc__ or ""

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kw)
    599             except Exception:
    600                 with util.safe_reraise():
--> 601                     metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
    602 
    603     def __init__(self, *args, **kw):

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py in __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     68             self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
     69             if not self.warn_only:
---> 70                 compat.raise_(
     71                     exc_value,
     72                     with_traceback=exc_tb,

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    205 
    206         try:
--> 207             raise exception
    208         finally:
    209             # credit to

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kw)
    594             metadata._add_table(name, schema, table)
    595             try:
--> 596                 table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
    597                 table.dispatch.after_parent_attach(table, metadata)
    598                 return table

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in _init(self, name, metadata, *args, **kwargs)
    669         # circular foreign keys
    670         if autoload:
--> 671             self._autoload(
    672                 metadata,
    673                 autoload_with,

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in _autoload(self, metadata, autoload_with, include_columns, exclude_columns, resolve_fks, _extend_on)
    704         insp = inspection.inspect(autoload_with)
    705         with insp._inspection_context() as conn_insp:
--> 706             conn_insp.reflect_table(
    707                 self,
    708                 include_columns,

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py in reflect_table(self, table, include_columns, exclude_columns, resolve_fks, _extend_on)
    788             raise exc.NoSuchTableError(table.name)
    789 
--> 790         self._reflect_pk(
    791             table_name, schema, table, cols_by_orig_name, exclude_columns
    792         )

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py in _reflect_pk(self, table_name, schema, table, cols_by_orig_name, exclude_columns)
    917         self, table_name, schema, table, cols_by_orig_name, exclude_columns
    918     ):
--> 919         pk_cons = self.get_pk_constraint(
    920             table_name, schema, **table.dialect_kwargs
    921         )

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py in get_pk_constraint(self, table_name, schema, **kw)
    526         """
    527         with self._operation_context() as conn:
--> 528             return self.dialect.get_pk_constraint(
    529                 conn, table_name, schema, info_cache=self.info_cache, **kw
    530             )

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/interfaces.py in get_pk_constraint(self, connection, table_name, schema, **kw)
    282 
    283         """
--> 284         raise NotImplementedError()
    285 
    286     def get_foreign_keys(self, connection, table_name, schema=None, **kw):

NotImplementedError:
```

From looking at the `opt/conda/envs/Python-3.8-main/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/interfaces.py`
most of the Dialect class methods seems to have no implementation in their functions and only raise `NotImplementedError()`.

Also looked into the `pandas/io/sql.py` file method `has_table` it seems that the query is always querying the `name` column from the `sqlite_master` table. Which, if I understand correctly, it `has_table()` never results in True.

```
 def has_table(self, name: str, schema: str | None = None):
        # TODO(wesm): unused?
        # escape = _get_valid_sqlite_name
        # esc_name = escape(name)

        wld = "?"
        query = f"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name={wld};"

        return len(self.execute(query, [name]).fetchall()) > 0
```

Thank you.

Comment: There seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/issues/102) for this on the db2 connector, but as yet no response from the maintainers.  Note that the project README states SQLAlchemy > 1.3.x is not supported.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - thank you for the explanation and the link to the open issue. Was not aware of it, I have not thought that sqlalchemy and pandas uses ibm-dbsa library under the hood, if I understand that right. Downgraded sqlalchemy to 1.3.0 with pandas 1.3.4 and it worked splendid.